# Brasero fails to read the multisession CD-R I want to copy

Tags: cd, burning, brasero

I want to copy a data CD-R that does not contain any copy protection mechanisms using Brasero on Ubuntu 16.04.

After starting the process, it begins to read the disk, but fails half way through. Below is the content of the generated error log (repeating lines shortened):

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
BraseroCdrdao stopping
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroCdrdao output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_CZ5EOY.bin toc = /tmp/brasero_tmp_CZ5EOY.toc
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_image_output
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_use_average_rate
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
    cdrdao
    read-cd
    --device
    /dev/sr0
    --read-raw
    --datafile
    /tmp/brasero_tmp_CZ5EOY.bin
    -v
    2
    /tmp/brasero_tmp_CZ5EOY.toc
BraseroCdrdao Launching command
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroCdrdao stderr: WARNING: Environment variable 'HOME' not defined- cannot read .cdrdao.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Cdrdao version 1.2.3 - (C) Andreas Mueller <andreas@daneb.de>
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: /dev/sr0: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUE1N   Rev: 1.00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Using driver: Generic SCSI-3/MMC - Version 2.0 (options 0x0000)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Reading toc and track data...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Track   Mode    Flags  Start                Length
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: ------------------------------------------------------------
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  1      DATA    4      00:00:00(     0)     08:24:06( 37806)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Leadout DATA    4      08:24:06( 37806)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: PQ sub-channel reading (data track) is supported, data format is BCD.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Raw P-W sub-channel reading (data track) is supported.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Cooked R-W sub-channel reading (data track) is supported.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Copying data track 1 (MODE1_RAW): start 00:00:00, length 08:24:06 to "/tmp/brasero_tmp_CZ5EOY.bin"...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 00:01:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 00:02:00
[...]
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 08:23:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: [valid=0] Info fld=0, Current 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: SCSI command failed: sense key: 0x05: Illegal Request
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Additional sense indicates: Invalid field in parameter list
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Raw sense data: 0x70 0x00 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 0x00 0x00 0x26 0x00 0x00 0x00 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: ERROR: Read error while copying data from track.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: HUP
BraseroCdrdao process finished with status 1
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_error
BraseroCdrdao finished with an error
BraseroCdrdao asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 0
    message = "no message"
BraseroCdrdao stopping
Session error : unknown (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2859)
```

**Update:**

I just found out that my original disc is a multisession CD containing two sessions.

What is the problem here and how can I finally copy my CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the issue is but have you tried other burning tools?

- [K3d](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k3b/) is great and very feature-rich in general. The amount of features may make it a little harder to use though. For a simple Job like this you can easily ignore them though.
- You can always use `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/tmp/backup.iso bs=8M` and a command-line CD burner. More at [How do I burn a DVD ISO using the terminal?](/q/174626/175814) or [Burning a CD or DVD using Command Line tools](//help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning#Command_Line_.28Terminal.29).

  If those fail with a similar error, I'd consider a firmware or hardware failure.

Comment: I looked at `k3b` already, but it depends on hundreds of KDE libraries and I'm not sure whether I want to install all those on my Unity machine...

Comment: `k3b` could read the disc correctly, but failed to burn the second session. Great, now I trashed a raw CD-R.

Comment: Yeah, maybe stick to a CD-RW or a DVD±RW first for this stubborn CD image. Burning the final CD after success with the rewritables should only take another 5 minutes annyway.

Comment: Okay, I fell back to Windows, downloaded the free trial of IsoBuster, extracted each session separately and am now manually merging them into one single directory structure and creating a new image I can burn from that. Curse the person who made this evil multisession disc!